# Check compressed archive for corruption

Tags: java, compression, archive, corruption, bzip2

I am creating compressed archives with `tar` and `bzip2` using [jarchivelib](http://rauschig.org/jarchivelib/) which utilizes [org.apache.commons.compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/).

```
try {
    Archiver archiver = ArchiverFactory.createArchiver(ArchiveFormat.TAR, CompressionType.BZIP2);
    File archive = archiver.create(archiveName, destination, sourceFilesArr);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Sometimes it can happen that the created file is corrupted, so I want to check for that and recreate the archive if necessary. There is no error thrown and I detected the corruption when trying to decompress it manually with `tar -xf file.tar.bz2` (**Note:** extracting with `tar -xjf file.tar.bz2` works flawlessly)

```
tar: Archive contains `\2640\003\203\325@\0\0\0\003\336\274' where numeric off_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `\0l`\t\0\021\0' where numeric mode_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `\003\301\345\0\0\0\0\006\361\0p\340' where numeric time_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `\0\210\001\b\0\233\0' where numeric uid_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `l\001\210\0\210\001\263' where numeric gid_t value expected
tar: BZh91AY&SY"'ݛ\003\314>\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\343\262\037\017\205\360X\001\210: Unknown file type `', extracted as normal file
tar: BZh91AY&SY"'ݛ�>��������������������������������������X�: implausibly old time stamp 1970-01-01 00:59:59
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Is there a way using [org.apache.commons.compress](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/) to check a compressed archive if it is corrupted? Since the files can be at the size of several GB an approach without decompressing would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `bzip2` compression produces a stream, there is no way how to check for corruption without decompressing that stream and passing it to `tar` to check.

Anyway, in your case you actually decompress directly with `tar` and not passing first to `bzip2`. This is the root cause. You need to always use the `-j` flag to `tar` as it's compressed by `bzip2`. That's why the second command works correctly.

Comment: I have hundreds of files which decompressed with `-xf` flags without problem. Only one made trouble. This, and for other failure prevention, I wanted to add a check for corruption. Nevertheless, my first reaction was to add the `-j` flag to my uncompress work-flow.

Comment: @bennos : Sure, it depends whether the file is compressed with `bzip2` or not. If yes, you have to provide `-j` flag as this does the `bzip2` decompression.

Comment: I meant decompressing hundreds of `bzip2` without the `-j` flag worked. I guess `tar` can identify the compression. Maybe this one had an error in the magic byte/header.